# nhibernate XmlSqlType

Tags: xml, nhibernate

I have been using NHibernate 2.2 for more than 1.5 years and it has been working great, until now.

I now have a need to map to SQL Server 2005's XML data type. I have found some custom IUserType implementations from the internet and they seem to make sense. But I have also noticed that the new NHibernate 3.2 appears to have a built-in XmlSqlType that looks like what I need.

According to the NHibernate 3.2.0 CR 1 / 3.1.0 - [Changelog](http://mac.softpedia.com/progChangelog/NHibernate-Changelog-57059.html), the new feature "NH-866" first appeared on NHibernate 3.0.0 Alpha 3. But I did not find anything regarding this feature on [NH reference page](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html) or anywhere else on the Internet. I did not find any references here either.

Apparently if NH 3.2 does not support the XmlSqlType I will need to go with the custom type approach but before I go down that path I'd like to make sure that I will not re-invent the wheel.

Any sugguestions,recommendations, examples or a URL references on this topic will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure NH does support the XmlSqlType, as it can be [found in the source](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/Default/Project/NHibernate/3.0.0.GA/Release/All/NHibernate/NHibernate/SqlTypes/XmlSqlType.cs)

So it should be located in the `NHibernate.SqlTypes.XmlSqlType` namespace.

Comment: Thanks Ron. I saw that source code as well. That confirms my understanding and that is great news! In that case the way to use it is simply map a property to a db column of XML type with a XmlSqlType in the mapping file such as <property name="PropertyName" column="ColumnName" type="XmlSqlType" not-null="false"/>? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I suppose so. Or, in case you didn't know, since nhibernate 3.2 you can create mappings in code too. (Since you specifically mentioned doing it in xml) See [this for code samples](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2011/04/nhibernate-32-mapping-by-code.html).

Comment: I read about the in-code mapping capability but I have not got a chance to actually test it out yet but I will try the conventional mapping using XML first to see how XmlSqlType works. I will update the post later with my findings. Thanks again.

Comment: I tried to map an XML column like this <property name="PropertyName" column="ColumnName" type="XmlDoc" not-null="false"/> and its corresponding entity class property like   public virtual XmlDocument Report { get; set; }. It appeared to be working. Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to map an XML column like this

```
<property name="PropertyName" column="ColumnName" type="XmlDoc" not-null="false"/>
```

and its corresponding entity class property like

```
public virtual XmlDocument Report { get; set; }.
```

It appeared to be working. Is this the right way to do it?

Can someone tell if this is a right way to do it?